# GCP Source Repository missing from All repositories list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-source-repositories

**TL;DR**

My `test-repo` is missing from `All repositories` list inside Cloud Source Repository panel, but I can still access it. Why?

Also asked [here on Google Cloud Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Operations/GCP-Source-Repository-missing-from-All-repositories-list/td-p/168467)

**Details**

1. I made `test-repo`
2. I was able to git clone using CloudSDK, make changes and even push.
3. When I went back to GCP Console > Cloud Source Repository, the repository did not show up and it showed me a welcome page.
4. I was still able to git pull.
5. I was able to access `test-repo` by going to my Cloud Function which was using the source code from `test-repo`.
6. When I made a new temporary repo caleld `test2`, it showed up under the `All Repositories` tab.
7. `test-repo` is still missing, but it shows up under `Recently Viewed` and I can access it there.

What is happening here???

[image]

[image]

Edit 1:
???
It is now only showing `test-repo` only.
[image]

Comment: Are you  authenticated / using the same user account under the web console and cloud SDK (`gcloud auth login`) ?

Comment: Yes I double-checked it.

Comment: Well, you are able to reach the repo on every step of the way using the Cloud SDK, and even using the UI at some point, so I would say this likely a UI issue in the GCP console. I recommend you to open an issue in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187169&template=0) so that they can be aware of the issue and work towards fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are able to reach your repository on every step of the way using the Cloud SDK, and even using the UI at some point, I would say this this is likely an UI issue in the GCP console.

That being said I recommend you to open an issue in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187169&template=0) so that Google Cloud's Engineering team can be aware of the issue and work towards fixing it.